# IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick when trying to migrate to another page?

Tags: java, android

I've been working on an app (which i took over from another student's final year project on my lecturer's recommendation) due to university internship requirements and am having issues with migrating from the main menu screen to the login screen.

(Only the login page has issues, going from the application's main menu to the register page has no issues whatsoever, hence i assume the problem might be either in the xml files or the LoginActivity.java, but have no idea how.)

logcat errors are listed as such:

```
TAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.finchvpn.androidcloudpark, PID: 1579
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:389)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:384)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438) 
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422) 
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601) 
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.finchvpn.androidcloudpark.MainActivity.loginButtonClick(MainActivity.java:74)
```

Below are related xml files:

Main menu xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"                xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/asd2">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="@drawable/side_nav_bar"
            app:popupTheme="@style/PopupOverlay" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_title"
            android:layout_width="239dp"
            android:layout_height="73dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:text="CloudPark.my"
            android:textColor="@color/md_white_1000"
            android:textSize="14pt"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.11"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.014" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/loginButtonPic"
            android:layout_width="132dp"
            android:layout_height="120dp"
            android:layout_gravity="end"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@null"
            android:onClick="loginButtonClick"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.19"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.559"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/loginnew2"
            tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/RegisterButtonPic"    
            android:layout_width="132dp"
            android:layout_height="120dp"
            android:layout_gravity="end"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@null"
            android:onClick="registerButtonClick"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.813"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.559"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/registernew1"
            tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="279dp"
            android:layout_height="63dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:text="CloudPark, the next generation parking app."
            android:textColor="@color/md_white_1000"
            android:textSize="10pt"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.505"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.181" />

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Login xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/asd2">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="@drawable/side_nav_bar"
            app:popupTheme="@style/PopupOverlay" />

       <TextView
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_title"
            android:layout_width="307dp"
            android:layout_height="91dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:text="Login"
            android:textColor="@color/md_white_1000"
            android:textSize="14pt"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.506"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

       <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="281dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:text="Enter your credentials to access CloudPark."
            android:textColor="@color/md_white_1000"
            android:textSize="10pt"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.505"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.181" />

       <EditText
            android:id="@+id/textUsername"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="Username"
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.503"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.352" />

       <EditText
            android:id="@+id/textPassword"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="Password"
            android:inputType="textPassword"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.503"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.443" />

      <Button
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:background="#0026FF"
            android:onClick="loginButtonClick"
            android:text="Login to CloudPark"
            android:textColor="#FFFF"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.687" />

      <android.support.constraint.Guideline
            android:id="@+id/guideline"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            app:layout_constraintGuide_begin="20dp" />

  </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

LoginActivity.java

```
public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private EditText textUsername;
    private EditText txtPassword;
    private static RestClient restClient = new RestClient();

    private SharedPreferences.Editor sharedPreferencesEditor;

    @SuppressLint("CommitPrefEdits")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

        try {
            Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
            setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

            Objects.requireNonNull(getSupportActionBar()).setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
            getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }

        textUsername = findViewById(R.id.textUsername);
        txtPassword = findViewById(R.id.textPassword);
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("UserInfo", 0);
        sharedPreferencesEditor = sharedPreferences.edit();
            textUsername.setText(sharedPreferences.getString("textUsername", ""));
            txtPassword.setText(sharedPreferences.getString("txtPassword", ""));
    }

    public static RestClient getRestClient() {
        return restClient;
    }

    public void loginButtonClick(View v) {
        if (!textUsername.getText().toString().equals("") && !txtPassword.getText().toString().equals("")) {
            apiPostLogin(Constants.ANDROID_KEY + ":" + textUsername.getText().toString() + ":" + txtPassword.getText().toString());
            sharedPreferencesEditor.putString("textUsername", textUsername.getText().toString());
            sharedPreferencesEditor.putString("txtPassword", txtPassword.getText().toString());
            sharedPreferencesEditor.commit();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "NULL", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

    private void apiPostLogin(String data) {
        final ProgressDialog progress = new ProgressDialog(this);
        progress.setTitle("Logging in");
        progress.setMessage("Please wait ...");
        progress.setCancelable(false); // disable dismiss by tapping outside of the dialog
        progress.show();
        Call<ResponseBody> call = getRestClient().getLoginService().postLogin(data);
        call.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<ResponseBody> call, Response<ResponseBody> response) {
                if (response.isSuccessful() && response.body() != null) {
                    try {
                        String data = response.body().string();
                        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(data);
                        Constants.uid = Integer.parseInt(jsonObject.getString("id"));
                        Constants.username = jsonObject.getString("username");
                        Constants.email = jsonObject.getString("email");
                        Constants.credit = jsonObject.getString("credit");
                        Constants.qr_code = jsonObject.getString("qr_code");
                        Constants.created_at = jsonObject.getString("created_at");
                        Constants.updated_at = jsonObject.getString("updated_at");
                        Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "apiPostLogin onResponse <<<< \r\n\r\n" + jsonObject.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
                        setResult(Activity.RESULT_CANCELED, returnIntent);
                        finish();
                    } catch (IOException | JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                progress.dismiss();
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<ResponseBody> call, Throwable t) {
                Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Incorrect username/password, please try again." + t.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                progress.dismiss();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: See this line in your logcat `Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.finchvpn.androidcloudpark.MainActivity.loginButtonClick(MainActivity.java:74)`.  It tells you some value/variable you are accessing in MainActivity on line no. 74 is Null

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect the problem is related with the clash of `android:onClick="loginButtonClick"` in main menu xml and login xml.

You should not depend on `android:onClick` attribute for handling View click. It is because when using `android:onClick` you can't be sure that your method handling the `onClick` will work. There is no exact mechanism to ensure your code is connected to the View. Another problem is, `android:onClick` **won't work for Fragment**. So, I consider using `android:onClick` as bad practice.

To solve the problem, use `setOnClickListener` on your View. Coupled with `findViewById`, your code will more robust because you will always see an error if you are giving an incorrect id for `findViewById`. To make your code more robust and avoid clashing the id, you need to use a decscriptive name id for the view. Use naming convention like this:

> `layout name` + `_` + `What the view for` + `_` + `type of view`

For example, for your login xml you can use something like this:

```
....

<Button
    android:id="@+id/login_cloudpark_btn"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:background="#0026FF"
    android:text="Login to CloudPark"
    android:textColor="#FFFF"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.687" />

<android.support.constraint.Guideline
    android:id="@+id/login_begin_gdl"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_constraintGuide_begin="20dp" />

...
```

then use it with `findViewById`:

```
public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

  ...

  private Button mBtnLogin;

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

    ...

    mBtnLogin = findViewById(R.id.login_cloudpark_btn);
  }
}
```

after that, add clickListener to `mBtnLogin`:

```
mbtnLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onClick(View v) {
         // place your clicking handle code here.
      }
    });
```

By doing the above, you will separate the View in xml and your logic cleanly.

Comment: Where should i place the last snippet of code at? I've tried placing it inside LoginActivity along with findViewById but it says cannot resolve symbol setOnClickListener.

Comment: place it after `mBtnLogin = findViewById(R.id.login_cloudpark_btn);`