# When retrieving Uri from DB - "Could not execute non-public method for android:onClick", e); Java

Tags: java, android-studio

I have an android app which stores information in an SQLite DB. On the activity I can open the Gallery, select a video, and then click on the "Watch Video" button and play that video.
HOWEVER, if I leave that activity and come back later, the saved URI IS in my DB, but loading it through the SAME onclick function produces this Exception error. ANY IDEAS WHY??

```
public void launchVideo(View view)  {
        if (my_video != null) {
            Uri uri = Uri.parse(my_video);
            Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            intent.setDataAndType(uri, "video/*");
            startActivity(intent);//THROWS ILLEGAL ACTIVITY WHEN WORKING FROM SAVED URI

        }
        else{...
```

Using debugger I see the following...

```
@Override
        public void onClick(@NonNull View v) {
            if (mResolvedMethod == null) {
                resolveMethod(mHostView.getContext());
            }

            try {
                mResolvedMethod.invoke(mResolvedContext, v);
            } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                throw new IllegalStateException(
                        "Could not execute non-public method for android:onClick", e);
            } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
                throw new IllegalStateException(
                        "Could not execute method for android:onClick", e);
            }
        }
```

Similar posts have mentioned issues being the xml or use of methods with the same name. I do not have any methods with the same name and the xml is below for the button:

```
 <Button
                android:id="@+id/watchVideo"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:onClick="launchVideo"
                android:text="@string/watch_my_video"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/youtube_link"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/youTubeEditText" />
```

The URI being passed in both the working and non working case is: "content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/video%3A595"

Finally in my Debugger I see the following which I take a confirmation everything is public:

```
mResolvedMethod = {Method@6254} "public void com.android.mybrazilianjiu_jitsudictionary.Controller.AttackDetail.launchVideo(android.view.View)"
 accessFlags = 134742017
 artMethod = 3966325964
 declaringClass = {Class@6043} "class com.android.mybrazilianjiu_jitsudictionary.Controller.AttackDetail"
 declaringClassOfOverriddenMethod = {Class@6043} "class com.android.mybrazilianjiu_jitsudictionary.Controller.AttackDetail"
 dexMethodIndex = 555
 hasRealParameterData = false
 parameters = null
 override = false
 shadow$_klass_ = {Class@3637} "class java.lang.reflect.Method"
 shadow$_monitor_ = -2092042593
```

My latest guess is it is related to:

```
try {
                    mResolvedMethod.invoke(mResolvedContext, v);
```

However, I am just trying to have the video appear in the user's video player via implicit intent which IS what happens until I leave the activity and come back. Note: via checking the database and Debugger the SAME URI is present and being passed to the method in all scenarios.

THANK YOU FOR YOUR INSIGHTS!

Answer (score 0):

By the following, I was able to fix the problem:

[IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick when trying to migrate to another page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50293776/illegalstateexception-could-not-execute-method-for-androidonclick-when-trying) was VERY helpful. On this advice I replaced my Button on click method with the following IN the OnCreate:

```
Button watchVideoButton = findViewById(R.id.watchVideo);

        watchVideoButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {...
```

The problem that then surfaced was lack of persistent permissions for the Uri when returning to the activity.

Persistent permission was taken via the following:

```
getContentResolver().takePersistableUriPermission(uri, FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
```

...which I placed BEFORE the onCreate in:

```
androidx.activity.result.ActivityResultLauncher<String> mGetContent = registerForActivityResult(new ActivityResultContracts.GetContent(),
        new ActivityResultCallback<Uri>() {
            @Override
            public void onActivityResult(Uri uri) {
                my_video = uri.toString();
                getContentResolver().takePersistableUriPermission(uri, FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
                Move move;
                move = new Move(MoveID,PositionTableID, MoveName, MoveStatus, GiY,AttackY, DefenseY, Description, internetVideoLink, my_video);
                myJiuJitsuDictionaryRepository.insert(move);

            }
        });
```